# Quadratic form.

Tags: linear-algebra, quadratic-forms

Consider the quadratic form $Q(v)=v^{t}Av,v=(x,y,z,w)$ where matrix $A$ is given by  \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 0 & 0 & 0  \\
    0 & 1 & 0 & 0  & \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
\end{bmatrix}

Then which of the following is true?

1. $Q$ has rank 3.
2. $xy+z^{2}=Q(Pv)$ for some invertible real matrix $P.$
3. $xy+y^{2}+z^{2}=Q(Pv)$ for some real invertible matrix $P.$
4. $x^{2}+y^{2}-zw=Q(Pv)$ for some some real invertible matrix $P.$

It is clear that $Q$ has rank $4$ so $1$ is not true. How about other options. Please help me . Thanks in advance.

Comment: I guess that $v = (x,y,z,w)$?

Comment: yes yes ...i am going to edit..thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to find the matrices that generate the forms on the left hand sides. For example,
$$
xy + z^2 = \left\langle\left(\begin{matrix}0 & \frac 1 2 & 0 & 0\\\frac 1 2 & 0 & 0 & 0\\0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\0 & 0 & 0 & 0\end{matrix}\right)\left(\begin{matrix}x \\ y \\ z \\ w\end{matrix}\right),\left(\begin{matrix}x \\ y \\ z \\ w\end{matrix}\right)\right\rangle.
$$
But this matrix has rank 3. Thus, no way.

Comment: okk sir now i will try ...thanks a lot....

Comment: I edited. The matrix I had before was not symmetric. Now, it's ok.

Comment: yes now its ok....

Comment: yes now i got the answer that is 4th one....thanks...

Comment: To be more precise: If $B$ is the found matrix above, you would have $\langle Bv,v\rangle = Q(Pv) = \langle APv,Pv\rangle = \langle P^TAPv,v\rangle$. By polarization, $B = P^TAP$ which cannot be true since $B$ has rank 3, but $P^TAP$ has rank 4 (since $P$ is assumed to be invertible).

Comment: $\begin{bmatrix} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\ 
\end{bmatrix}$ if we do $R_3\to 1/2 R_3$ and $R_4 \to 1/2 R_4$ we get \begin{bmatrix} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1/2 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1/2 & 0\\ 
\end{bmatrix}. Can we say that there is a matrix $P$: $P^T \begin{bmatrix} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1/2 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1/2 & 0\\ 
\end{bmatrix}P$ =$\begin{bmatrix} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\ 
\end{bmatrix}$?